# What does "omit" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [a discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/526295/is-it-wrong-when-ignoring-the-event-year-in-generalized-difference-in-difference/526400?noredirect=1#comment969887_526400), Thomas Bilach mentioned that

> And by "reference" I mean the pre-treatment epoch. In a typical event
> study framework evaluators may assess effects in all periods before
> and after treatment. In essence, we're assessing the evolution of
> effects in reference to the omitted period.
>
> The period we **omit** is our reference period. In applied work,
> evaluators typically drop a pre-treatment period. The period you omit
> is up to you, but the period immediately before treatment starts is a
> popular choice. Does that make sense?

I am wondering if **omit** means **desire** in this case

Comment: "omit" never means "desire"  (but if you think I'm wrong please give an example)   Omit means "leave out or exclude"  (dictionary defn)

Comment: I think it is the meaning from the dictionary, but I cannot fit this word in this context by this meaning, that is why I am doubting about thee meaning tho.

Comment: Can you link the dictionary or type out the words written in your dictionary?

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh I mean the meaning of "omit" is similar to what being said by James K, but it seems not to fit in this context the link of the dictionary is [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/omit)

Comment: Uh-huh, now I get your statement. Sorry about that. I mean they are trying to tell that the period we omit (from our talk/conversation/speech/etc.) is called the reference period. I really need to read the whole article before commenting anymore, but there doesn't seem to an alternate meaning to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As James mentioned, *omit* never means *desire*.

> **omit** (verb) - *leave out or exclude (someone or something), either intentionally or forgetfully*

A previous response in that thread words it differently:

> The justification is that we need a reference period. In most impact evaluations the authors typically drop the period immediately before treatment.

compared to your highlighted comment:

> The period we omit is our reference period. In applied work, evaluators typically drop a pre-treatment period.

Both are saying to *leave out* or *omit* the period directly before treatment to use as a reference period.